# XSD for an element, when an element can be both mandatory and optional

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have two possible variants of an XML:

1. Both 'ElementB' and 'ElementC' are mandatory.

```xml
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB /> 
        <ElementC />
    </ElementA>
```

2. both 'ElementB' and 'ElementD' are mandatory, but 'ElementC' is optional.

```xml
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB /> 
        <ElementC />
        <ElementD />
    </ElementA>
```

I need something like

```xml
<xs:group name="ElementsD">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ElementC " type="ElementCType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="ElementD " type="ElementDType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="ElementA">
   <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ElementB " type="ElementBType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="ElementC" type="ElementCType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:group ref="ElementsD" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This schema does not work due to

> ElementC and ElementC (or elements from their substitution group)
> violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this
> schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 3):

So this is possible with XSD 1.1 which includes support for `xs:assert`; I do not think this is possible with XSD 1.0 using just the regular `sequence`, `choice` compositors. If you need to use XSD 1.0 then I think you're out of luck.

However, in XSD 1.1, the test logic that should work is: `<xs:assert test="(ElementB and ElementC) or (ElementB and ElementD)"/>`.

Using the above assertion logic also means that both `ElementC` and `ElementD` should be optional (`minOccurrs="0"`).

Here's the schema (I've added a `Root` element to allow testing multiple permutations in a sample XML document):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="ElementBType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ElementCType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ElementDType"/>

    <xs:element name="ElementA">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ElementB" type="ElementBType"/>
                <xs:element name="ElementC" type="ElementCType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ElementD" type="ElementDType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="(ElementB and ElementC) or (ElementB and ElementD)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ElementA"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's an example XML document that is associated with the above schema and demonstrates the test cases:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SO77537687.xsd">
    <!-- OK: B, C -->
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB></ElementB>
        <ElementC></ElementC>
    </ElementA>
    <!-- OK: B, C, D -->
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB></ElementB>
        <ElementC></ElementC>
        <ElementD></ElementD>
    </ElementA>
    <!-- OK: B, D -->
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB></ElementB>
        <ElementD></ElementD>
    </ElementA>
    <!-- All of these fail: B alone fails, C alone fails, and D alone fails. -->
    <!-- Also C, D fails because B isn't present -->
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB></ElementB>
    </ElementA>
    <ElementA>
        <ElementC></ElementC>
    </ElementA>    
    <ElementA>
        <ElementD></ElementD>
    </ElementA>    
    <ElementA>
        <ElementC></ElementC>
        <ElementD></ElementD>
    </ElementA>
</Root>
```

Comment: I'm learning something on this one :)
For reference, [XSD assertions documentation here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<xs:sequence>` inside `<xs:choice>`. This allows you to define multiple sequences that may occur within an element (but only one of them is allowed at once in any occurrence of said element).

```xml
<xs:element name="ElementA">
   <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="ElementB" type="ElementBType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 <xs:element name="ElementC" type="ElementCType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="ElementB" type="ElementBType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 <xs:element name="ElementC" type="ElementCType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 <xs:element name="ElementD" type="ElementDType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but your variant is quite the same as mine. The XSD is not valid: `ElementB and ElementB (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.`

Comment: Does it work if you put the declaration for `ElementD` at top of the second sequence declaration? Since parsers sometimes parse in a lazy way and the ambiguity in my code may be caused by the `elementB` being declared at top of both sequences. If it does not work either, this would mean that an element can't be declared as both mandatory and optional.

Comment: Yes, it works. But unfortunately, this is not an option :( The sequence of elements is predefined and can't be changed.