# How to define a schema definition which has a choice of one of one element, or multiples of another element

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to make a schema definition for a type that can have a couple of formats, but I'm not quite sure how best to do it.

The XML block I'm trying to make a type for will cover entries like this:

```
<Object>
    <Filter> <!-- 0 or 1 of these -->
       <!-- Filter stuff -->
    </Filter>
    <MapObject> <!-- 1 or more of these
      <!-- Map Object stuff -->
    </MapObject>
</Object>

OR 

<Object>
    <Filter> <!-- 0 or 1 of these -->
       <!-- Filter stuff -->
    </Filter>
    <UpdateObject> <!-- 1 or more of these
      <!-- Update Object stuff -->
    </UpdateObject>
</Object>
```

I could just go with an xs:sequence like:

```
    <xs:complexType name="ObjectType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Filter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="FilterType"/>
            <xs:element name="MapObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="MapObjectType"/>
            <xs:element name="UpdateObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="UpdateObjectType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

But I want to make sure I have at least 1 MapObject or UpdateObject, and I can allow multiple MapObjects (but only 1 UpdateObject), and we can't mix MapObject and UpdateObject.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how best to define this in a schema definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XSD 1.1, you can use `assert` logic operator :

It would look like the following :

```xml
<xs:complexType name="ObjectType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <!-- Filter 0 or 1 of these -->
    <xs:element name="Filter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="FilterType"/>
    <!-- MapObject : undefined if UpdateObject or 1 min (no max) -->
    <xs:element name="MapObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="MapObjectType"/>
    <!-- UpdateObject : undefined if MapObject or 1 max -->
    <xs:element name="UpdateObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="UpdateObjectType"/>
    <xs:assert test="(MapObject and !UpdateObject) or (!MapObject and UpdateObject)"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

See documentation [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions)

If XSD 1.1 is out of question, you could have that kind of logical check in your backend server (that's what I would have done before knowing the `xs:assert` operator).

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537687/xsd-for-an-element-when-an-element-can-be-both-mandatory-and-optional)

Comment: Thanks. That's the sort of thing I'm looking for I think. 

Sadly I don't think we can use XSD 1.1, but I'll probably include it in the definition (commented out) and let our parser handle things later as needed since mixing Update and Map object elements shouldn't happen normally anyways.